# TFVC: Build is looking in the wrong directory

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc

I was having problems with Git in VSTS and so I was instructed to switch to TFVC. The hope was that all I need to do for the build process is switch the "`Get Sources`" to the new TFVC repository which has the same code.

What I am finding in the build is that it is failing, it is looking for packages in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise` and this directory does not exist as I am not using VS Enterprise, instead I am using Professional and the folder exists for that.

So how can I get the build process to look in the right place?

UPDATE FOR ANSWER:
What I found during the migration from Git to TFVC was that some items that appeared to be checked in were not found in the build. One item missing from the build was Automapper and I decided it would do no harm to update the Automapper Nuget package to the latest version. The idea was that if I check in and build again, would Automapper continue to be found missing in the build?
I was surprised to find that when I checked, a whole number of other artifacts also appeared for the checkin. So I checked them all in and the build succeeded this time. I do not know why this happened or if anyone would benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last post, your build was queued by **Hosted VS2017 agent**. So the [Enterprise VS2017](https://github.com/adventworks/hosted-pool-images/blob/2017.10.01/vs2017-on-windows-2016/image.md) used to build your project is located on VSTS server not your development machine.

If you need to build project by your development machine, you should setup a [**private agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) on it.

Comment: OK that is useful to know. For now we keep the Hosted Agent and I am wondering how to fix this? See https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhERQL5GdvI4rz3XzJMr11-avED- for the log files.

Comment: Did you add the reference in source control? It seems VSTS can not find the references.

Comment: The package.config is in Source control. When I look at VS it is not possible to put references in SC

Comment: What's the content of `StandardClassLibrary.csproj`? You may need to change the reference paths.

Comment: For example EF is not being picked up, and it's path is C:\Users\{secret}\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SIR\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll

Comment: And the library you asked about; C:\Users\{secret}\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SIR\StandardClassLibrary\bin\Debug\StandardClassLibrary.dll

Comment: For the references like EF, you should change the path as `..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\E‌​ntityFramework.dll`. For the references like the library, first please make sure the library is added in source control, then change the path as `..\StandardClassLibrary\bin\Debug\StandardCla‌​ssLibrary.dll`. You can also refer the similar issue in this post 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039846/vsts-building-asp-net-core-2-0-compile-error-could-not-locate-the-assembly

Comment: I have only just seen your last comment Marina. In the meantime what I did was get the latest version of Automapper from Nuget just to see if that would still come up as missing in the build. When I checked in there was a lot of items that suddenly appeared ready for checking in, and when I did I got a clean build. So I do not know why this happened, it must be one of those odd things when migrating from GIT to TFVC.

Comment: It's depend on how did you do when migrate Git to TFVC. But you can verify by adding your code to a new repo or a new branch. And since the question is quite different from the initial question you asked, you can create a new post for the issue you meet now. And since the answer helps you solve the initial question, you cam mark the answer.